# angularjs how to know if a page is cached or not?

Tags: java, angularjs, caching

I have a java/angular application. I know that angular partially caches html pages, and I don't want to prevent it doing that cause at somepoint it speeds up my application.
But on the other hand when I deploy the application for the customers, they never know the page that they are watching, is it cached or the new version that I have deployed. I tried to get the version of the manifest from a restful service, like this

```
    InputStream inputStream = servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");
    Manifest manifest = new Manifest(inputStream);
    return Response.ok(manifest).build();
```

but this won't help because it will get the build version which is always updated.
Do you have any idea how can I have something to check the version of html pages? any thing rather than hard coding a version in html page?

Comment: Why do the customers need to know whether a page is cached? Why do you need to cache a page at all? You can set the cache headers, so the browser makes a freshness check when needed and delivers the page from the browser cache, if no modification was detected.

Comment: They don't want to cache anything! I just imagined this partial caching can make the application faster! Doesn't it?!